# Cassette.Nancy unbundled files returning 404

Tags: nancy, cassette

I've added `Cassette.Nancy` to an existing Nancy web project. This works fine when I set `CassetteNancyStartup.OptimizeOutput = true;` but when this is set to `false` I get 404 on the unbundled resources.

Here's my set up.

I'm using the following packages:

- Cassette.Nancy version="2.1.1"
- Cassette version="2.4.1"
- Nancy version="0.22.2"
- Nancy.Owin version="0.22.2"
- Nancy.Viewengines.Razor version="0.22.2"

The files are like so:

- Content

  - file1.css
  - file2.css
- Scripts

  - script1.js
  - script2.js

CassetteBundleConfiguration:

```
public class CassetteBundleConfiguration : IConfiguration<BundleCollection>
{
    public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.AddPerSubDirectory<StylesheetBundle>("Content");
        bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("Scripts");
    }
}
```

in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Bundles.Reference("Content");
    Bundles.Reference("Scripts");
}

@Bundles.RenderStylesheets()
@Bundles.RenderScripts()
```

And finally in `Bootstrapper`:

```
public Bootstrapper()
{
    CassetteNancyStartup.OptimizeOutput = false;
}
```

Like I say this works fine when `CassetteNancyStartup.OptimizeOutput` is set to `true` but when `false` each of the resources return a 404 like this one:

```
GET http://localhost:10005/_cassette/asset/Content/file1.css?cf7a7edf515a8184a0c53ec498c583cc64bb0e63 404 (Not Found)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was down to me not adding the Owin handler in the `web.config`. Adding this fixed it.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Owin" verb="*" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```